# VIFM was working normally, then, suddenly, started crashing with error message on startup: "Segmentation fault: 11"

Tags: macos, runtime-error, vifm

VIFM was working normally on OSX Yosemite. My system crashed because of an unrelated issue and, when I booted it back, I noticed VIFM wouldn't open anymore. Typing "vifm" on the terminal only shows an error message:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Segmentation faults are bugs. You should report this to vifm.

Comment: Off topic, belongs to SU. This is more about using a software than writing one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what was wrong, but I managed to fix my issue by trial and error by replacing `~/.vifm/vifminfo` with a brand new one, downloaded from the sources. I'm posting this here to help someone with the same problem, since I couldn't find any solution online.

Comment: Do you still have that broken `vifminfo` file around? It was broken in some strange way and situations are quite hard to reproduce intentionally.

Comment: I don't, I'm sorry :(